# Programatically added attribute, set to 'show on product page' automatically. Woocommerce

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, woocommerce-offtopic, codex, page-attributes

Ive written a script to import products to a new install of Woocommerce.

The products have attributes set up in the admin.
This bit of code adds the attributes on import.

```
update_post_meta($product_id, 'common_name', $product['common_name']);
wp_set_object_terms($product_id,  $product['flowering_period'], 'pa_flowering');
wp_set_object_terms($product_id, $product['native_plant'], 'pa_native');
```

However when I look at the product attribute in admin, the tick box for 'show on product page' is unticked.

Is there a way to set this as ticked using the above function? 
OR
Does it matter if this is ticked or not, if I call the attribute in the template directly using something like get_the_term_list (although most of my attributes have a single term) will it show, or does having this box ticked overide it showing up?

Comment: Automattic bough Woozone, Woocommerce will shortly be part of Wordpress core. Stop closing these questions as off-topic, it's annoying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It actually doesn't matter because WooCommerce uses this, to display:

```
$values = wc_get_product_terms( $product->id, $attribute['name'], array( 'fields' => 'names' ) );
```

However, if you don't set the display to true, you'd have to add this code to your template files. You might have to do other things as well (styling, etc). If you just set the display to true, you don't have to do anything. WooCommerce will take care of it.

this is how WooCommerce does it, roughly (/includes/class-wc-ajax.php):

```
wp_set_object_terms( $product_id, $values, $attribute_name);

// get existing attributes

$attributes = get_post_meta( $product_id, '_product_attributes' );

$attributes[ sanitize_title( $attribute_name ) ] = array(
        'name'          => wc_clean( $attribute_name ),
        'value'         => $values,
        'position'      => $attribute_position, // the order in which it is displayed
        'is_visible'    => $is_visible, // this is the one you wanted, set to true
        'is_variation'  => $is_variation, // set to true if it will be used for variations
        'is_taxonomy'   => $is_taxonomy // set to true
);


// this part sorts the attributes before saving based on the position value 
// this is defined by WooCommerce, but if your import runs before WooCommerce is loaded, this function won't be available
if ( ! function_exists( 'attributes_cmp' ) ) {
    function attributes_cmp( $a, $b ) {
        if ( $a['position'] == $b['position'] ) {
            return 0;
        }

        return ( $a['position'] < $b['position'] ) ? -1 : 1;
    }
}

uasort( $attributes, 'attributes_cmp' );

// update it back
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_product_attributes', $attributes );
```